# How to apply a function to a column in R data frame and store output in one dataframe

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, apply

I have a data frame like this

```
set.seed(12)
df=data.frame(a=runif(20,-100,100),b=rep(c("a","b"),10))
```

Now I need to figure out what % of values in column 'a' that have absolute value < n, and n is a variable: 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, and output the result into a data frame like this

```
n              10 20 30 40 50
% in the range 12% 14% 27% 40% 50%
```

Comment: So what is the actual output you desire? Your example output data.frame isn't very clear.

Comment: I've edited the answer (with dummy value). hope it's clearer.

Comment: Do those actually correspond to the example input data you provided? Are "n" and "% in range" supposed to be a column and column header in the data.frame? Is this purely for presentation?

Comment: so n is a variable in a function to be applied to df column 'a', to figure out which % of col 'a' value are within the bound of n value. as long as the output of n and % can be in one data frame or list, the format doesn't matter. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a method to return a data frame

```
# get a named vector of values
myValues <- setNames(seq(10, 50, 10), seq(10, 50, 10))
# return result
data.frame(lapply(myValues, function(x) sum(abs(df$a) < x) / nrow(df)))
X10  X20  X30 X40 X50
1 0.1 0.15 0.35 0.4 0.5
```

It is even simpler to return a named vector with the same information.

```
myPropVec <-sapply(myValues, function(x) sum(abs(df$a) < x) / nrow(df))
myPropVec
  10   20   30   40   50 
0.10 0.15 0.35 0.40 0.50
```

It is straightforward to plot the named vector as a bar chart:

```
barplot(myPropVec)
```

[image]

Or using `dotchart`:

```
dotchart(myPropVec)
```

Comment: thanks Imo. Any way I can plot out the output in a line or bar chart?

Answer (score 2):

for a list result:

```
n <- seq(10,50, by = 10)
list <- lapply(n, function(x) percent(sum(abs(df$a) < x)/nrow(df)))
setNames(list, n)
```

for a data frame:

```
df <- do.call(rbind, list)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this could work to give you a vector output

```
n<-seq(10,50,10)

perc<-vector()

for(i in 1:5) {perc[i]<-sum(abs(df$a)<n[i])/length(df$a)}

perc
[1] 0.10 0.15 0.35 0.40 0.50
```